# When running static files through node.js, how do I call a function defined in the node.js document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Lets say I have this code saved in `index.js`:

```
const serveIndex = require('serve-index');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/project', express.static('public'))
app.use('/project', serveIndex('public'))


app.get('/', (req, res) =>; {
    res.send('Server Running.');
});

function createAccount() {

// Create Account
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "database1"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `confirm_code`, `confirmed`, `plugin1`, `plugin2`, `plugin3`, `plugin4`, `plugin5`, `myplugin1`, `myplugin2`, `myplugin3`, `myplugin4`, `myplugin5`) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + email + "', '" + code + "', 'no', 'none', 'none','none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none');";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () =>; console.log('App running on port 3000.'));
```

And in my `public` file, I have a javascript file running this:

```
var username = "John Doe";
var password = "1234";
var email = "johndoe@example.com";
var code = "1234";

createAccount();
```

How do I get the `createAccount()` function to run properly when the js file in the `public` folder is run? (As in it creates the account with all the information provided in variables)

Comment: `createAccount()` needs to accept those as parameters, and you'll need something like an HTTP POST request to send the data from the client to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. The simplest way is to just export that information to your main `index.js` file and then pass it into your `createAccount()` function.  With the way you currently have that `index.js` file, all of the username, password etc are undefined. So you'd have to import them from your `public` file at the very least.

The *proper* way to do this, though, would be to create a function that sends an HTTP(S) POST request to wherever your web server is located along with the relevant information. Then, you just make a callback function that will accept the option params in the request and pass them along into your `createAccount()` function, which will in turn execute the SQL command as you wrote it already in your OP.

Comment: I'm pretty new to node.js, so is there anywhere you can link me where there is documentation for this?

Comment: This is what you would use for the POST request: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback (though alternatively you could just use Express)